# Dynamically configure the data source for WebServiceClient's wsdlLocation

Tags: java, spring

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4ddk.png)
In the above photo, the data source for wsdlLocation is configured using a static code block because wsdlLocation = is configured in the @WebServiceClient annotation "classpath:wsdl-dev/SI_TGMES_PROORDERCOMPLETE_OutService.wsdl", is not valid, is there any way to dynamically configure wsdlLocation = "Classpath: the environment/path", the value of the environment, alternative content for yml file configured in the startup type such as dev or test, after the completion of the replacement is the wsdlLocation = "classpath: dev/path" And make wsdlLocation work or is there any way to switch new in a static block of code Is the wsdl-dev in the URL("classpath:wsdl-dev/SI_TGMES_PROORDERCOMPLETE_OutService.wsdl") changed to dev or test in the yml configuration? Thank you for your advice

1. @1.@value annotation is not valid in static code blocks
2. wsdlLocation = "classpath:@Value('${wsdlURL}')/SI_TGMES_GETMATERIALIST_OutService.wsdl".is not valid
3. use configuration class is not valid